Software-boutique can not be start in Ubuntu24.04 LTS
I upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Software boutique is not starting at all.
Solution is not working:

I removed it:
sudo snap remove software-boutique

I reinstalled:
sudo snap install software-boutique --classic

Then started: software-boutique --classic


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/726/usr/bin/ubuntu-mate-welcome", line 30, in <module>
    gi.require_version("WebKit2", "4.0")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 125, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available for version %s' %
ValueError: Namespace WebKit2 not available for version 4.0

sudo apt-get install webkit2gtk-4.1 did not help.

same thing with snap ubuntu-mate-welcome

it look likes this software has been archived look at https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/software-boutique-2.0

Does this answer your question? software-boutique won't start because of a missing dependency, So what does replace software-boutique?

it look likes this software has been archived look at https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/software-boutique-2.0   so there may be no support for this one, got to try something else.
I succeeded to launch software boutique in noble after installing
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 that I have taken back from the jammy's repositories.
But it doesn't show any installable software now. I guess there is only snap-boutique left for you to use. Try to replace software-boutique  with gnome-software
